# Getting error "IndexError: list index out of range" when I try to use an activation function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, neat

So I'm trying to write a game that uses NEAT to evolve the players in typical NEAT fashion, but the activation function gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "C:/Users/me/py/neat.py", line 101, in main
output = nets[homies.index(ind)].activate((ind.x, abs(obs[0].x - ind.x)))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do here. I just kind of followed along with a Tech with Tim NEAT tutorial and I got this error, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Here's the full code if you need it:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import os
import neat

W = 300
H = 300
win = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("bruv moment")


coords = [0, 60, 120, 180, 240]


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = 600 - 60
        self.width = 60
        self.height = 60
        self.pos = 0
        self.left = False
        self.right = False

    def move(self):
        if self.left:
            self.pos -= 1
        if self.right:
            self.pos += 1
        if self.pos < 0:
            self.pos = 4
        if self.pos > 4:
            self.pos = 0
        self.x = coords[self.pos]


class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, vel):
        self.pos = pos
        self.x = coords[self.pos]
        self.y = -60
        self.width = 60
        self.height = 60
        self.vel = vel

    def move(self):
        self.y += self.vel


def redraw_window():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, W, H))
    for ob in obs:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (ob.x, ob.y, ob.width, ob.height))
    for ind in homies:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (ind.x, ind.y, ind.width, ind.height))
    pygame.display.update()


obs = []
homies = []
player_collision = False

ge = []
nets = []


def collide():
    for ob in obs:
        for x, ind in enumerate(homies):
            if ind.y < ob.y + ob.height and ind.y + ind.height > ob.y:
                if ind.x + ind.width > ob.x and ind.x < ob.x + ob.width:
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    homies.pop(x)
                    nets.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)


def main(genomes, config):
    speed = 30

    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 550)
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 2, 1000)

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        homies.append(Player(0))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    ran = True
    while ran and len(homies) > 0:
        clock.tick(27)
        collide()
        for x, ind in enumerate(homies):
            ind.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[homies.index(ind)].activate((ind.x, abs(obs[0].x - ind.x))) <== ERROR TRACEBACK

            if output[0] > 2:
                ind.left = True
            else:
                ind.left = False
            if output[1] > 2:
                ind.right = True
            else:
                ind.right = False
        for ob in obs:
            ob.move()
            if ob.x > H:
                obs.pop(obs.index(ob))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                ran = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == USEREVENT+1:
                if speed <= 200:
                    speed += 3
            if event.type == USEREVENT+2:
                for g in ge:
                    g.fitness += 0.5
        if len(obs) == 0:
            obs.append(Block(round(random.randint(0, 4)), speed))
        redraw_window()


def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet,
                                neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "avoidpedofiles.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Comment: if you get `list index out of range` then check length of list(s) and check value(s) which you use as index - ie. `print( len(nets), homies.index(ind) )` `print( len(obs) )`. Errors means that your list is shorter then you expect and there is no element with index which you use.

Comment: BTW: if you enumerate values on list `for x, ind in enumerate(homies):` then you can use `x` instead of `homies.index(ind)`  in `nets[x]` - if you have two elements `ind` then `homies.index(ind)` will give always index of first element and you never get second element but `x` will have correct index and you will get correct element.